# Angular 2: how to unit test a component whose ui is dependent on a third party library

Tags: unit-testing, angular

We have a component which relies on a third party library. This third party liberary is responsible to provide a table to show my data. In our component we are calling various APIs exposed from that liberary to do certain tasks. So basically my template url is null and we are generating our view at run time.
The operations on ngonint are related to sorting of data,inserting data to cell etc.

```
//component
@component({selector: 'mytable', templateUrl:'URL of template'}
export class mycomp{ 
//data members
constructor (element ref injection, @Attribute('sample string') private sampleString:string){}
//public methods
private ngOninit(){ this.dataview = dataview of third party lib.    }
}

//Test
Describe("my test",()=>{ 
beforeEachProviders(()=>[ mycomp, provider for elementRef]);

It('test', async(inject ([TestComponentBuilder,mycomp], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
tcb.createAsync(mycomp)
.then ((fixture)=> {
expect(true). toBe(false)
})
 });
```

Comment: please provide samples of your code showing what you have tried so far; with Angular 2 issues, the best would be to isolate the issue and provide a plunker  : https://plnkr.co/   Also, you may consider reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why negative vote. I am deliberately trying to avoid a scenario specific answer and so no code.. If someone knows what I am talking about he/she will be able to guide me in right direction. Please don't downgrade just because you can.

Comment: Sorry your feelings got hurt. It is not against you, though. Your question was downvoted to let you know that, according to me, you should rephrase it, because it is too broad; and too compact, which makes it difficult to read. When your question has been rephrased, I will reconsider. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127058/negative-votes-necessary-for-newbie   Also, other members of the community may think differently and upvote. Most members are here to help: if you make your question more appealing and answerable you will get answers and upvotes.

Comment: :) added code. However this gives error at the moment. as mentioned in this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448301/error-no-provider-for-attributesamplestring

Comment: The error is not related to the 3rd-party lib but to `@Attribute('sample string#)` in your code above. To me it looks like the same question as the one you linked to in the previous comment. Please consider deleting this question if it is the case.