# error: No provider for @Attribute('sampleString')

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

We are trying to write unit test for a component which uses a third party java script library. The constructor of our component looks like -

```
@Constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) private eleref:ElementRef, @Attribute('sampleString') private sampleString: string)
```

We use that attribute to pass it to my third party library. And in there it does a specific task based on that attribute. If I don't pass it, it means simply ignore it and do regular stuff.

When we try to use/inject this component in our test class, it gives us error.

```
Error: DI Exception: No Provider for @Attribute('sampleString')!
```

Can someone suggest for what would be the provider for this? If your example can elaborate why this error and how to solve such issues in general, that will be bonus.

```
//component
@component({selector: 'mytable', templateUrl:'URL of template'}
export class mycomp{ 
//data members
constructor (element ref injection, @Attribute('sample string') private sampleString:string){}
//public methods
private ngOninit(){ this.dataview = dataview of third party lib.    }
}

//Test
Describe("my test",()=>{ 
beforeEachProviders(()=>[ mycomp, provider for elementRef]);

It('test', async(inject ([TestComponentBuilder,mycomp], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
tcb.createAsync(mycomp)
.then ((fixture)=> {
expect(true). toBe(false)
})
 });
```

Comment: I tried to create an "artificial" provider for `@Attribute(...)` but wasn't able to find a way. How do you test? Does it work if you create a test component that wraps this component like `<my-component sampleString="foo">`? AFAIK this is the only way to make the `@Attibute(...)` decorator on a constructor argument work.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. Can you help with providing more details about what could be the exact reason of this error. That may give some hint for me to look into my code.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing. Can you post more code? How do you inject? This `@Attribute(...)` only works if the component is created from the view of a parent element where this attibute is added to the elements tag.

Comment: That's not a lot of context. Please add some code.

Comment: To give more context.. This third party library provides a table. We change this pure JavaScript library to a angular 2 component using code. @component({ selector: 'table', template URL: URL location}).  Now that we have a component we want to write unit test for this component itself..    Regarding invoking this component, yes you are right, I will be using this table component in another component and there we will call the component in the HTML of that component.. Like <table #id sampleString></>

Comment: You need to create a test component that has `<table #id sampleString></table>` in its template and create an instance using `TestComponentBuilder` and the use the debugElement you get from TCB to get a reference to the table element. If you create the component this way the `@Attribute(...)` injection should work.

Comment: Wouldn't this take me to the actual JavaScript library. E.g. I wanted to call a method x of my angular2 component (which is built on top of that third party library) but fixture.debugElement will not give me access to such methods..

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about. I think seeing some code would help tremendously ;-)

Comment: First of all, thank you for being so prompt to help me. The reason I am not pasting code is that I am not allowed to put any code outside. I will try one last time to explain everything without code.. So we wanted a table, a third party(TP) lib suits our requirement, so we took it. Instead of using that lib directly, we wrap it in an angular component using dataview. My new component has some methods like get, set, change, ngoninit etc.  I am trying to write unit test for this component. the moment I use my new component in inject. It gives me error for no provider and then for @attribute

Comment: I can't make sens from these prose descriptions. A few lines of could would probably make it all obvious.

Comment: //component
@component({selector: 'mytable', templateUrl:'URL of template'}
export class mycomp{ 
//data members
Constructor (element ref injection, @Attribute('sample string') private sampleString:string){}
//public methods
Ngoninit(){ this.dataview = dataview of third party lib }
}

//Test
Describe("my test",()=>{ 
Beforeeachproviders(()=>[ mycomp, provider for elementRef]);

It('test', async(inject ([testcomponentbuilder, mycomp], (tcb: testcomponentbuilder) => {
tcb.createAsync(mycomp).then ((fixture)=> {
Expect(true). tobe(false)
})
 }.  //Adding from mobile can't format

Comment: Aas mentioned earlier, you need to wrap the component in a test component to be able to get `@Attribute(...)...` injected. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute needs to be

```
@Attribute('sampleString')
```

instead of

```
@Attribute('sampleString')
```

You need a test component that wraps the component that you actually want to test to be able to pass the attribute:

```
@component({
  selector: 'mytable', 
  templateUrl:'URL of template'
}
export class mycomp{ 
  //data members
  constructor (element ref injection, @Attribute('sampleString') private   sampleString:string){}
  //public methods
  private ngOninit(){ this.dataview = dataview of third party lib.    }
}

@component({
  selector: 'test', 
  template:'<mytable sampleString="xxx"></mytable>'
}
export class TestComponent{ 
}

//Test
describe("my test",()=>{ 
  beforeEachProviders(()=>[ mycomp, provider for elementRef]);

it('test', async(inject ([TestComponentBuilder,mycomp], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
  tcb.createAsync(TestComponent)
 .then ((fixture)=> {
    expect(true). toBe(false)
    // get the mycomp component from fixture ...
  })
});
```

Comment: so, we are injecting myComp and creating TestComponent? btw, I did try both when you suggested the very first time. However, I couldn't figure out a way to call public methods of 'myComp' in order to unit test those? The fixture or debugElement of it doesn't give much help..? Any idea how to get those ?

Comment: fixture.debugElement should provide all you need https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DebugElement-class.html. You can also add `@ViewChild(mytable) myTable;` to `TestComponent` then you can access the `myTable` instance in the test using `fixture.componentInstance.myTable;` (after `fixture.detectChanges()` because `@ViewChild()` AFAIR)

Comment: @viewchild way, grid returns as undefined . have opened a bug at github.. But given there are 1000+ issues, I am not very hopeful. Let me know if you think any other scenario worth a try..

Comment: And what about querying from `debugElement`?

Comment: Have same issue and wrapping of element not helped, it still can't find that dependency. @GünterZöchbauer do you have some simple code on plunkr to show it works? Thanks in advice.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, sorry, my bad, there was another test which includes component directly. It's working! Thanks!

Comment: @TypeScripter, also check this one template https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/5b4ef6dc0d8e35126c789d91c4932f9062660816/addon/ng2/blueprints/component/files/__path__/__name__.component.spec.ts helped my a lot. Strange that they changed it to the new version, which is not working at all. But that version works.

Comment: @vladimir, what am I looking at? A little more insight will be helpful. It will also help if you can post your code to show the problem and how you solved it.

Comment: @TypeScripter, here it is https://gist.github.com/bobrosoft/0d869161f3aef16350dc8c73db8e2e91  Check EditFriendComponentTestController which wraps EditFriendComponent which we actually are going to test.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, it helped. Wish I could give you and @GünterZöchbauer , multiple up votes :)