# How to set providers for annotations used inside the constructor?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, karma-jasmine

Consider the following class structure

```
@Component({selector: 'myComp', template: '<div></div>'})

export class MyComp {

//Variables...

constructor( @Inject(ElementRef) private elementRef: ElementRef, 
@Attribute('highlight') private highlight: string) { }

//Methods ...
```

Now in other class or in unit test's describe block I need to set provider for injecting this class.

In my unit test I have

```
beforeEachProviders(() => [MyComp, ElementRef ,Attribute ]);
```

Which is incorrect, I need to know what's the correct way to provide ElementRef and @Attribute to make it work.

Error I was facing is

```
Error: No provider for @Attribute(highlight)! (MyComp-> @Attribute(highlight))
    Error: DI Exception
```

Edit: attribute 'highlight' is a boolean attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
import {addProviders, inject, TestComponentBuilder} from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('my code', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    //addProviders([MyService]);
  });

  it('does stuff', inject([TestComponentBuilder, MyService], (tcb, service) => {
    tcb.overrideProviders({provide: ElementRef, useClass: MockElementRef})
    .createAsync(ExternalTemplateComp).then((componentFixture) => {
  });
});
```

I don't know a way to provide an `@Attribute()` dependency.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38496290/217408 for a workaround.

Comment: ElementRef is fine, @Attribute is the problem.
I tried that workaround on that link. still the same error that no provider for @Attribute(highlight)

Comment: I know, this is why I posted the link to the other question

Comment: any other workaround to create component Instance of myComp and access it's method?

Comment: As far as I know - no - not when you have an `@Attribute()` parameter. Might be worth a bug report though.